# dnsmasq cannot create listening socket for PXE boot

Tags: networking, server, remote-desktop, pxe, dnsmasq

I'm trying to set up a LTSP server so I can have thin clients all around our office, but for the time being, after following [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2173749) tutorial, whenever I try to run:

```
sudo service dnsmaq start
```

or

```
sudo service dnsmaq restart
```

I get the output:

```
* Starting DNS forwarder and DHCP server dnsmasq 
dnsmasq: failed to create listenning soccket for 192.168.1.86: Address already in use.      [fail]
```

Upon running `sudo service dnsmasq stop` then `sudo netstat -anpl | grep -w LISTEN` I can see that the dnsmask service is still listening with PID 1638, but on 192.168.122.1 which makes no sense to me. If someone could shed some light here I would be glad, but it's not the main problem.

After killing the process with the `sudo kill 1638` and trying to restart I still get the same error. Upon running `ifconfig` I can see that the eth0 network adapter is with the address 192.168.1.86

I think it's worth noting that were running a WDS PXE boot server on the same network and I don't know if this has anything to do with this problem, that to me seems like it's a server-side issue.

Cheers,